# get an iterator from any struct or tuple by key of a field as string

Tags: c++, boost, struct, iterator, tuples

Do you know a library in boost, poco, ... that has a function with a signature such as :

```
template <typename T> auto vectorize(const std::vector<std::string> & mask, T & t) -> T::iterator
```

which could be used like :

```
struct A {double x; double y; double z;};
auto a = A();
auto it = vectorize({"x","z"}, a);
//and here doing perturbations and increments on a; ideally it is for passing it to another function
```

I am redesigning existing code that does such a thing (with a method for serializing inside the struct) but I have to admit our version is quite messy :/

Do you have an idea of abstraction for that and working with tuples ?
I am currently trying with an enum for mapping the field of the tuple.

I am pretty sure that someone wrote something intelligent for this kind of reflexive container iteration problem. (I have looked to boost::fusion but it doest filtering by types only or I missed a page)

Comment: Do you have to use `struct A` as is?  Are the contained types always uniform, for example all doubles?

Comment: for the moment I use `struct A` as is plus a `serialize()` function as member. For giving some background I have a library quite similar to `boost::numeric::odeint` and some algorithm have to be able to manipulate a substate of my system like if it was a vector. For the moment I have only `double` or `std::vector<double>` mainly (maybe some users have specific needs) but I want to go for using either `boost::unit` or unit with constexpr as Stroustrup shown in its presentations.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have any magic ways of doing this nicely like many of the VM languages.

Usually you'd use something like [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).  The goal being that you just write a simple mapping function, and the rest is just configuring policies.

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

class gps_position
{
public:
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
        degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
    {}
};

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, gps_position & g, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & g.degrees;
    ar & g.minutes;
    ar & g.seconds;
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

Alternatively, you may be able to get some traction with something simple that assumes that you're always serializing doubles or write static visitors for `std::tuple` or `boost::tuple` if you're not using c++11.